# Change layering of dynamic objects

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am making a Flash game and have a quick query about layering / order of objects that are dynamically added to the stage. I have the mouse cursor replaced by a crosshair with enemy ships flying across the screen, but the problem I am having is that the enemy ships appear above the crosshair so that when I go to 'target' a ship, the crosshair is not visible as it is under the ship. How can I change this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you. I have added an extra line of code in the following functions:

```
function sendEnemy(e:Event)
{
    var enemy = new EnemyShip();
    stage.addChild(enemy);
    stage.addChild(crosshair);//brings crosshair to topmost level on stage
}

function sendEnemyMed(e:Event)
{
    var enemymed = new EnemyShipMed();
    stage.addChild(enemymed);
    stage.addChild(crosshair);//brings crosshair to topmost level on stage
}

function sendEnemySmall(e:Event)
{
    var enemysmall = new EnemyShipSmall();
    stage.addChild(enemysmall);
    stage.addChild(crosshair);//brings crosshair to topmost level on stage
}
```

After you add anything on stage you just need to update crosshair's z-index by calling 'stage.addChild(crosshair)' which brings the crosshair again on the topmost level.

Answer (score 1):

setChildIndex() - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#setChildIndex%28%29

or

swapChildren() -http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#swapChildren%28%29

Depending what you would like to do.

Comment: Hi, I was looking at these funnily enough but as I am just a beginner I wasn't too sure how I would go about using it?

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer will indeed work, sometimes it's best to take a design approach that addresses the problem and makes it less of a headache.

For example you could create a layer called enemyLayer :

```
var enemyLayer:Sprite = new Sprite;
```

You would then add your enemyLayer first to the stage, and then your crosshair :

```
stage.addChild(enemyLayer);
stage.addChild(crosshair);
```

Whenever you add an enemy, you would add it to the enemyLayer :

```
enemyLayer.addChild(enemy);
```

With a design approach like this, you don't need to worry about constantly manipulating your crosshair to ensure it's on top. The crosshair will ALWAYS be on top.

Answer (score 0):

You may add each spaceship with method `addChildAt(spaceship, 0);` where zero is index which should be less than or equal to crosshair's index. You may also create separate Sprite for your spaceships. And add it to stage before you add crosshair.